# Can't access my API that was published to IIS (local)

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

It's my first time to publish an ASP.Net Core 2.1 so I'm not quite sure what I'm missing.  When I try to just run the API from VS2017, I can access all Requests(CRUD) through **POSTMAN** or even directly the browser by localhost:1111/api/MyRoute.

After I deployed it in IIS and tried **mywebsite.com/api/MyRoute**, the request shows correct details of the request in **Developer Console > Network** but shows error in the console of **ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK)**

I also tried Attaching the process in VS2017 through **w3wp.exe** still doesn't hit the **Get Request**

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Are your deploying to your local IIS or remote IIS? it seems more like a connection issue, I would suggest that you call your webapi through ip address instead of domain. `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200` indicate the connection to your server failed, it may result from DNS failure

Comment: Saw you publish to IIS local, can you check if you have bind your website to mywebsite.com in IIS? meanwhile, did you change your host file so that mywebsite.com can point to localhost?

Comment: downvoted, this is supposed to be a comment not as an answer to my question.  anyway I deployed it on my local IIS.  and also Yes for both, I binded my website in IIS and changed also the host file from system32 to point to localhost

Comment: try to comment but not enough reputation so has to raise this as an answer